# Size of Facebook Event Picture

Tags: java, android, facebook

I am trying to fetch the information of a facebook event using a request by the Facebook SDK for Android, but I am getting a small image. The fetching procedure is done as follows:

```
params.putString("fields", "id,name,picture");
mAsyncRunner.request("me/events",params, new RequestListener() {.....
```

But the link to the JPG image is very small. Is there any way to get a better resolution of this image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you know the EVENT_ID for a particular event, you can send a graph request to "EVENT_ID/picture?type=SIZE" where SIZE=small | normal | large.